# Google Play Realtime Notifications SUBSCRIPTION_EXPIRED not received on expiration time

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am trying to implement the backend logic for android purchases of an app and started integrating using [android document](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/realtime_developer_notifications).

During the tests, I am able to get `SUBSCRIPTION_PURCHASED`, `SUBSCRIPTION_RENEWED` and `SUBSCRIPTION_CANCELED` but I do not see any `SUBSCRIPTION_EXPIRED` when the time for expiration comes. According to the documentation
`SUBSCRIPTION_EXPIRED` - A subscription has expired
and after `SUBSCRIPTION_CANCELED` user is supposed to keep the subscription until the period he/she has paid is over (i.e the expiryTime on token verification response).

Once a subscription is canceled, is it the server on our side who is supposed to terminate the subscription-based on the expiry time info with the token and SUBSCRIPTION_EXPIRED is sent for a different case?

And if "`SUBSCRIPTION_EXPIRED` is sent for a different case" is correct, what is the time/case for `SUBSCRIPTION_EXPIRED` notification?

Comment: Hi denizdurmus, did you ever find the answer to this question, as i'm in the exact same situation?

Comment: @MatthewM at first they said i am supposed to get the expiration notifications, but then in their last mail to me, they said "Please note that notificationType=3 will be cancel the subscription hence you will not receive expire notification since it has been canceled." so waiting for an expiration notification is kind of useless, both for tests and real production purchases

Comment: @denzidurmus, thanks for getting back so quickly. Yeah, the expiration notification seems useless then!

Comment: @denzidurmus Did you hear anymore about this? We are having the same issue.

Comment: @M0rty nope, no updates at other than my comment above. As a workaround, I have placed checks based on the expiration date we keep on our own database to deal with the expirations by cronjobs.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that there is not 100% guarantee that notifications will be received

For me it is much safer to call this code periodically or every time the app is initialized

> billingClient.queryPurchases (BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS);

If the subscription has expired, it will return that the user does not own the item and you should enable/disable features based on this and not on notifications

Comment: agreed with the safer option, though i have already found bunch of workaround to handle similar cases within the backend server.